# Pushing to GitHub with Pycharm and Two Factor Authentication

Tags: git, authentication, github, pycharm, two-factor-authentication

Using Pycharm, I have configured it to connect to my GitHub account where I have two-factor authentication enabled. When I first open Pycharm, I have the option to pull down from GitHub, where it has be log in (or saves my credentials) but then prompts me for my authentication token, which works fine. It pulls down the repo just as it should. The problem stems when I try to commit and push files back up. I execute the commit, give it a description, then try to push the commit, and I login at this dialog:

[image: Pycharm git login]

The problem here is that it doesn't give me the opportunity to enter my two-factor authentication token for the push, and the authentication fails.

Is there any way to:

1. Have Pycharm re-prompt for the token
2. Cache the token from the initial login (less secure of course)
3. Set up the equivalent of a "Google Application Password" where it has a separate tokenless password for just this one application (much less secure)

Or is this just a bug that needs reported? I have just started using Pycharm, but couldn't find much useful information on this subject.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/registering-github-account-in-intellij-idea.html?origin=old_help, if setup correctly you should be prompted for the authentication code

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. If you want to post it as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Links on their own aren't too helpful here, but if you've the time to write up what you did with it you can provide a good answer to your own question!

Comment: Fair nuff, I'll do that, along with screenshots.... thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to jonrsharpe for pointing me in the right direction, here is what I did to resolve this:

In the `Settings` menu, under `Version Control`, there is a `GitHub` section. In here, there is an `Auth Type` dropdown, where you can select Password or Token. (See Image)  Selecting token will prompt you for your authentication token, then create an API key that will bypass the need for a token directly during a push. This was exactly what I needed.

[image]

Comment: Worked for me too. Why is't it setup by default - the current behavior seem to be broken.

Comment: This helped me as well. We have year 2017 at the moment, and only the "Token" option works.

Comment: This no longer seems to be working for me. the Git Settings panel no longer has the "Auth Type" dropdown.

Comment: The screen has changed at the time of commenting.

Comment: The screen has changed at the time of commenting.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, the interface has changed slightly since [Tim S's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36107419/11411686). Rather than a dropdown, there's now an "Enter Token" link in the "Log In to Github" dialog.

[image]

[image]

[image]